# iPhone UIActivityIndicator not working at first launch

Tags: iphone

It works fine on every subsequent launches. I'm using an OpenGL animation at the start, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

The activity indicator is hidden and inactive by default.
Call [activityIndicator startAnimating] to start it manually.

Good luck!